# Make Ext js menu stay open

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu

I'm showing an ext js menu from a button, the default behaviour is that the menu is hidden when you click outside of it. How can I make it fixed until I click the button again?

```
xtype: 'button',
    text: 'MyButton',
    menu: {
        xtype: 'menu',
        showSeparator: false,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'colorPickerWidget',
                listeners: {
                    colorchange: {
                        fn: me.onColorPickerWidgetColorChange,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: show more code, where we can observe `me` declaration

Comment: What do you mean by me?

Comment: check your pasted code. There is `me` property or object in your code. Show where it was declared

Comment: There is no code... the colorpickerWidget is simply a widget that is included inside. It could be anything even a simple panel or container.

Comment: really? So why it throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: me is not defined` ?! Show more code to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different approach:

In the `onClick` event handler of your button create a new window (`Ext.Window`) that includes your `colorPickerWidget`. Also check if your window already exists. In this case, hide it.

Upon creating the window make sure that property `modal: false` (the default value) and set the position of the window (x & y properties). You can get the 2 values from your button (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element))